# Messagequeue left behind after uninstallation

Tags: wix, wix3, wix-extension

I use MsmqExtension to create a private message queue. But during uninstall the queue is left behind without any rights and can't be deleted manually.

What am I missing?

This is a little test setup I wrote:

```
<util:Group Id="Admins" Name="Administrators"/>
<util:Group Id="Everyone" Name="Everyone"/>

<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="WixProject1">
      <Component Id="cmpCCFCC98FF29F9839A11C5E93C1B73C3E" Guid="510DB8D1-A435-42A8-A8E8-5A4695CFBD7C" KeyPath="yes">
        <msmq:MessageQueue Id='CreateTQ'
               Label ='Test Queue'
               PathName='.\Private$\Test_Queue'
               Transactional='yes'>

          <msmq:MessageQueuePermission Id='CreateTQPermissions_Admins'
                                       QueueGenericAll='yes'
                                       Group='Admins' />

          <msmq:MessageQueuePermission Id='CreateTQPermissions_Everyone'
                                       GetQueueProperties='yes'
                                       GetQueuePermissions='yes'
                                       WriteMessage='yes'
                                       Group='Everyone' />
        </msmq:MessageQueue>
      </Component>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="WixProject1" Level="1">
  <ComponentRef Id="cmpCCFCC98FF29F9839A11C5E93C1B73C3E"/>
    </Feature>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can call a CustomAction on uninstall. And in the customaction you can write your own code to delete messagequeue

```
<Custom Action="DeleteMSMQ" After="InstallFinalize">REMOVE</Custom>
```

This action will be called only on **REMOVE**.